# TestNG shows 0 Test run

Tags: java, selenium, testng, assert

I'm trying to execute my test scripts using testNG and trying the below code, but 0 displayed against run, fail and skip in the console. Because of that I'm unable to verify the results in my script.

Java:

```java
package com.demoaut.newtours.testcases;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

//import junit.framework.Assert;
public class TC002_CheckAssert {
    @Test
    public TC002_CheckAssert() {
        System.out.println("ajkcbh");
        try {
            Assert.assertEquals("Pass", "Pass");
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception:" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I am executing the above script through testng.xml file.

```
<suite name="Suite">
  <test name="Test">
   <classes>
      <class name="com.demoaut.newtours.testcases.TC002_CheckAssert" />
   </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

Console results:

```
ajkcbh

"==============================================="
Suite
Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
"==============================================="
```

Comment: are you running with maven command?

Comment: no. I am not using maven.

Comment: are you sure you are seeing `ajkcbh` this in output. this means your test are actually running. one more thing, in which IDE are you running this test, if it's **elicpse** are you sure **testng** plugin in installed.

Comment: @Durgesh - You would need to tell us how are you running this test ? It also has a compilation error. Without a return type a method cannot be defined. So I am not sure how you got this test class to even compile (So I am guessing that its perhaps a copy paste error) ? Also can you please add `verbose="3"` to your suite xml file in the `<suite>` tag and share the complete output ?

Comment: Actually the problem was  I had written code in the constructor and if we use Assert statements in constructor then they don't work.when I used them in a method (i.e. changed my constructor to method by giving return type and changing its name) then it worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a minor bug in your code block. When you are using `TestNG` and writing methods within `@Test` annotation, we should define the methods with proper **`return types`**. I have used your own code and simply added the **return type** as **void** as follows:

```
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Q45191867_Assert_Pass_Suite 
{

    @Test   
    public void TC002_CheckAssert() 
    {
        System.out.println("ajkcbh");
        try
        {
            Assert.assertEquals("Pass", "Pass");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception:"+e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

The code block executes successfully when executed as `TestNG Test`.

I have executed the code block converting into `TestNG` with the following `testng.xml` as follows:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="demo.Q45191867_Assert_Pass_Suite"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

I have executed this code block again as `TestNG Suite`. In this case as well the output on the console was:

```
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\AtechM_03\LearnAutmation\LearnAutomationTestNG\testng.xml

ajkcbh

===============================================
Suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Comment: so is it basically requires an assertion, is that right?